# How to find unresolved links in web pages with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a way in VS2012 to scan the web pages in a project for dead links?  I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666926/tool-to-find-dead-links-css-js-anchors-in-a-local-web-page but I'm asking specifically for VS2012 and that question seems to be more generic.